# Best way to redirect to an URL if it is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two tabs, In my Controller I have written the follwing:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ViewSongAmendments")]
[AuthorizeTenancy(Roles = "super,administrator")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ViewSongAmendments(string songCode, int page = 1, int take = Constants.MVC.Pagination.DefaultItemsPerPage,
                                        string sortBy = "Membership", bool sortAsc = true)
{
    // AJAX?
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ViewSongAmendments", "SongsManagement");
    }

    return await GetWorkAndAmendmentDetails(songCode, page, take, sortBy, sortAsc);

}

[HttpGet]
[Route("UpdatedSongAmendments")]
[AuthorizeTenancy(Roles = "super,administrator")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdatedSongAmendments(string songCode, int page = 1, int take = Constants.MVC.Pagination.DefaultItemsPerPage,
                                        string sortBy = "Membership", bool sortAsc = true)
{
    // AJAX?
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return RedirectToAction("UpdatedSongAmendments", "SongsManagement");
    }

    return await GetWorkAndAmendmentDetails(songCode, page, take, sortBy, sortAsc);
}
```

But this is what my Controller looks like, is there a better method that I could use to do the redirect. As usual, I use:

```
// AJAX?
if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return View(model);
}
return PartialView("_ViewAmendmentsWriters", model);
```

**Controller**

I have added my controller, as I would like to return the model if it is not an Ajax request. But I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("ViewSongAmendments")]
    [AuthorizeTenancy(Roles = "super,administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ViewSongAmendments(string songCode, int page = 1, int take = Constants.MVC.Pagination.DefaultItemsPerPage,
                                            string sortBy = "Membership", bool sortAsc = true)
    {
        return await GetWorkAndAmendmentDetails(songCode, page, take, sortBy, sortAsc);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("UpdatedSongAmendments")]
    [AuthorizeTenancy(Roles = "super,administrator")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdatedSongAmendments(string songCode, int page = 1, int take = Constants.MVC.Pagination.DefaultItemsPerPage,
                                            string sortBy = "Membership", bool sortAsc = true)
    {
        return await GetWorkAndAmendmentDetails(songCode, page, take, sortBy, sortAsc);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the work and amendment details.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="songCode">The song code.</param>
    /// <param name="page">The page.</param>
    /// <param name="take">The take.</param>
    /// <param name="sortBy">The sort by.</param>
    /// <param name="sortAsc">if set to <c>true</c> [sort asc].</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<ActionResult> GetWorkAndAmendmentDetails(string songCode, int page, int take, string sortBy, bool sortAsc)
    {
        var workAndActiveAmendments = await _artistAccountService.GetWorkAndActiveAmendmentGraphAsync(songCode, includeRecordingArtifact: true, includeWorkSplitsAndWriters: true);
        var workAndActiveAmendmentsViewModel = MapWorkAmendmentToSongAmendmentsComparisonModel(workAndActiveAmendments);

        workAndActiveAmendmentsViewModel.PagingInfo = new PagingModel
        {
            Page = page,
            Take = take,
            SortAscending = sortAsc,
            SortPropertyName = sortBy,
            PipedFilter = string.Empty
        };
        return View(workAndActiveAmendmentsViewModel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maps the work amendments to work view model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="viewModel">The view model.</param>
    /// <param name="domainAccountModel">The domain account model.</param>
    private static ViewModels.SongAmendmentsComparisonModel MapWorkAmendmentToSongAmendmentsComparisonModel(WorkGraph.WorkAndAmendment workAndAmendment)
    {
        var viewModel = new ViewModels.SongAmendmentsComparisonModel
        {
            OriginalWork = new WorkAmedmentsComparisonModel
            {
                // meta
                ID = workAndAmendment.Original.ID,
                RowVersion = workAndAmendment.Original.RowVersion,
                IsDeleted = workAndAmendment.Original.IsDeleted,
                IsNew = workAndAmendment.Original.IsNew,

                // data
                Title = workAndAmendment.Original.Title,
                DurationMins = workAndAmendment.Original.DurationMins,
                DurationSecs = workAndAmendment.Original.DurationSecs,
                Iswc = workAndAmendment.Original.Iswc,
                UniqueCode = workAndAmendment.Original.UniqueCode,
                Version = workAndAmendment.Original.Version,
                IsRemix = workAndAmendment.Original.IsRemix,
                ContainsSample = workAndAmendment.Original.ContainsSamples,

                // nav items
                AlternativeTitles = workAndAmendment.Original.AlternativeTitles != null
                    ? workAndAmendment.Original.AlternativeTitles
                        .Select(x => new WorkAmendmentsAlternativeTitle
                        {
                            // meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            // data
                            Title = x.Title
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<WorkAmendmentsAlternativeTitle>(),

                PerformingArtistNames = workAndAmendment.Original.PerformingArtistNames != null
                    ? workAndAmendment.Original.PerformingArtistNames
                        .Select(x => new WorkAmedmentsPerformingArtistName
                        {
                            // meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            // data
                            Firstname = x.Firstname,
                            Lastname = x.Lastname,
                            IPIBaseNumber = x.IPIBaseNumber,
                            IPINameNumber = x.IPINameNumber
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<WorkAmedmentsPerformingArtistName>(),

                Recordings = workAndAmendment.Original.Recordings != null
                    ? workAndAmendment.Original.Recordings
                        .Select(x => new WorkAmedmentsRecording
                        {
                            // meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            // data
                            ISRC = x.ISRC,
                            PerformingArtist = x.PerformingArtist,
                            RecordLabel = x.RecordLabel,
                            ReleaseDate = x.ReleaseDate,
                            Title = x.Title,

                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<WorkAmedmentsRecording>(),

                Splits = workAndAmendment.Original.WorkSplits != null
                    ? workAndAmendment.Original.WorkSplits
                        .Select(x => new WorkAmedmentsSplit
                        {
                            //meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            //data
                            RightToCollect = x.RightToCollect,
                            WriterShare = x.WriterShare,
                            WriterDesignationCode = (ViewEnums.WriterDesignationCodeType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ViewEnums.WriterDesignationCodeType), x.WriterDesignationCode),
                            Society = x.RelatedWriter.Society != default(DomainModels.Society) ? x.RelatedWriter.Society.Name : string.Empty,

                            // nav
                            SplitWriter = new WorkAmendmentsWriter
                            {
                                ID = x.RelatedWriter.ID,
                                RowVersion = x.RelatedWriter.RowVersion,
                                IsDeleted = x.RelatedWriter.IsDeleted,
                                FirstName = x.RelatedWriter.FirstName,
                                MiddleName = x.RelatedWriter.MiddleName,
                                LastName = x.RelatedWriter.LastName,
                                CaeIpiNumber = x.RelatedWriter.CaeIpiNumber,
                                PublisherCaeIpi = x.RelatedWriter.PublisherCaeIpi,
                                PublisherName = x.RelatedWriter.PublisherName,
                                UniqueCode = x.RelatedWriter.UniqueCode,
                                WriterUnknownIndicator = x.RelatedWriter.WriterUnknownIndicator,
                            }
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<WorkAmedmentsSplit>(),


            },
            // Updated Track Details
            ActiveAmendmentWork = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment == default(WorkGraph.WorkAmendment)
                ? default(ViewModels.WorkAmedmentsComparisonModel)
                : new WorkAmedmentsComparisonModel
                {
                    // meta
                    ID = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.ID,
                    RowVersion = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.RowVersion,
                    IsDeleted = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.IsDeleted,
                    IsNew = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.IsNew,

                    // data
                    Title = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.Title,
                    DurationMins = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.DurationMins,
                    DurationSecs = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.DurationSecs,
                    Iswc = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.Iswc,
                    UniqueCode = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.UniqueCode,
                    Version = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.Version,
                    IsRemix = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.IsRemix,
                    ContainsSample = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.ContainsSamples,

                    // nav items
                    AlternativeTitles = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.AlternativeTitlesAmendments != null
                    ? workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.AlternativeTitlesAmendments
                        .Select(x => new WorkAmendmentsAlternativeTitle
                        {
                            // meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            // data
                            Title = x.Title
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<WorkAmendmentsAlternativeTitle>(),
                    PerformingArtistNames = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.PerformingArtistNameAmendments != null
                    ? workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.PerformingArtistNameAmendments
                        .Select(x => new WorkAmedmentsPerformingArtistName
                        {
                            // meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            // data
                            Firstname = x.Firstname,
                            Lastname = x.Lastname,
                            IPIBaseNumber = x.IPIBaseNumber,
                            IPINameNumber = x.IPINameNumber
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<WorkAmedmentsPerformingArtistName>(),

                    Recordings = workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.RecordingAmendments != null
                    ? workAndAmendment.CurrentAmendment.RecordingAmendments
                        .Select(x => new WorkAmedmentsRecording
                        {
                            // meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            // data
                            ISRC = x.ISRC,
                            PerformingArtist = x.PerformingArtist,
                            RecordLabel = x.RecordLabel,
                            ReleaseDate = x.ReleaseDate,
                            Title = x.Title,
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<WorkAmedmentsRecording>(),

                    Splits = workAndAmendment.Original.WorkSplits != null
                    ? workAndAmendment.Original.WorkSplits
                        .Select(x => new WorkAmedmentsSplit
                        {
                            //meta
                            ID = x.ID,
                            RowVersion = x.RowVersion,
                            IsDeleted = x.IsDeleted,

                            //data
                            RightToCollect = x.RightToCollect,
                            WriterShare = x.WriterShare,
                            WriterDesignationCode = (ViewEnums.WriterDesignationCodeType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ViewEnums.WriterDesignationCodeType), x.WriterDesignationCode),
                            Society = x.RelatedWriter.Society != default(DomainModels.Society) ? x.RelatedWriter.Society.Name : string.Empty,

                            // nav
                            SplitWriter = new WorkAmendmentsWriter
                            {
                                ID = x.RelatedWriter.ID,
                                RowVersion = x.RelatedWriter.RowVersion,
                                IsDeleted = x.RelatedWriter.IsDeleted,
                                FirstName = x.RelatedWriter.FirstName,
                                MiddleName = x.RelatedWriter.MiddleName,
                                LastName = x.RelatedWriter.LastName,
                                CaeIpiNumber = x.RelatedWriter.CaeIpiNumber,
                                PublisherCaeIpi = x.RelatedWriter.PublisherCaeIpi,
                                PublisherName = x.RelatedWriter.PublisherName,
                                UniqueCode = x.RelatedWriter.UniqueCode,
                                WriterUnknownIndicator = x.RelatedWriter.WriterUnknownIndicator,
                            }
                        })
                        .ToList()
                    : new List<WorkAmedmentsSplit>(),
                }
        };

        // return
        return viewModel;
    }


};
```

}

Comment: "a better method that I could use to do the redirect" can you clarify what you mean? Better how? If you want to redirect when the request is not an AJAX request then this is the correct method to use.

Comment: Okay thanks, Its just when I try and change the songcode in the url it to see if it working it says that I have too many requests.

Comment: Does it say too many "Redirects" or too many "Requests"? It may be that you are creating an infinite loop by making "ViewSongAmendments" go back to the same "ViewSongAmendments" URL. You shouldn't be redirecting to the same action you are already inside.

Comment: It says: redirected you too many times.

Comment: You are creating an infinite loop. Both actions redirect to themselves, which then continues until you get the error. Remove the "RedirectToAction".

Comment: What would I replace it with though?

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: Baically retuen the model if its not an Ajax Request. I will add my controller now.

Comment: If you want to return the model as JSON then you can use `return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. But you can return anything you want, for example `return new EmptyResult()`, anything that is an ActionResult? Can you be more specific in what you want?

Comment: Basically something like, where model is each model.

`{
    return View(model);
}`